# How to store the cumulative sum of rows of matrix as rows, and not as columns in R?

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, types

[image: The snapshot of my code]

When i apply cumsum on rows, the resultant values is stored in columns but when i apply it on columns, it is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `apply` is not going to change its return value based on the `MARGIN` you use, as this would give unexpected consequences (e.g. what would you want if you use a margin like `c(1,2)`?)

You can always flip the results with `t()` though.

Comment: Thanks t() works if it is a n*n matrix(for eg: 4*4) but what for m*n matrix(for eg: 3*5)?

Comment: `Apply` will turn your 3*5 matrix into a 5*3 matrix, which will then be turned back into a 3*5 matrix by `t()`